# virtualbox - How to make "localhost" point to the host's "localhost"?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, localhost, hosts

I know I can access the host's localhost using `10.0.2.2`. However, what I need is to to be able to type "localhost" in my VirtualBox Edge browser and for it to point to the localhost of my computer.

I have tried a couple thing with the `host` file, but no success yet. Is it even possible to do what I want?

Cheers!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? What do you mean by "I can access the host"? Do you have a webserver running on the host?

Comment: localhost is `127.0.0.1`. It is local host, not another host...

Comment: Exactly, I have a webserver that is running on the host. On the host, I can access this webserver with "localhost". On the VM, I want to also be able to access the webserver with "localhost".

Comment: No you don't as that would crash your system

Comment: *De rien..*  **>:-)** Thanks for the acceptance and upvote, favour returned, question upvoted!  **;-)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TL;DR

*Nope! Sorry! Cannot be done!*

### The long version:

As per [RFC1122, section-3.2.1.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1122#section-3.2.1.3) the localhost is defined as:

> (g)  `{ 127, <any> }`
> Internal host loopback address.  Addresses of this form MUST NOT appear outside a host.

Thus `localhost` cannot be re-mapped even at the `/etc/host` file level as the driver bypasses the `host` file for that particular item.

Having said the above, *this is free software, so you have the source code of the kernel available to you* but even if you would become a kernel developer and start creating a custom kernel *that would allow you to do that*, you'll run into a ton of routines everywhere which will assume `localhost` = `127.0.0.1` *hardcoded* so that would just be *extremely difficult* (=years of work) but as you're talking Edge Browser you'd have to get Microsoft on your side as well and ... well ...

#### That's not going to happen! :-(

<sub>Sorry, neat idea but unfeasible...</sub>

Comment: That's too bad. My web pages on my host are all pointing to a localhost server. When I open the web pages in the VM, which are pointing to localhost, of course, it doesn't work. I need to change the "localhost" paths (HTTP requests to localhost:3030, which is my local server) of my webpages to "10.0.2.2" every time I need to run the website on the VM. Great answer BTW. Thanks!

Comment: OTOH: just make `https://1.0.2.2` your home page... **¯\\_(ツ)_/¯**

Comment: Haha that would not work. `https://10.0.2.2` is the web server that serves `index.html`. But there is javascript code on this page that makes HTTP requests to `https://10.0.2.2:3030`, so the code would need to be modified. Thanks for the effort though ;).

Answer (score 3):

You can't change what `localhost` alone means, but the question isn't really about remapping localhost, but about getting http://localhost:80 to load the Host OS's port 80. **This is certainly possible!**

In the below examples, the host's LAN ip is 10.0.2.2 – change this if yours is different:

If the guest is **Windows**, you can use netsh portproxy. Run cmd.exe as administrator, then type

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=80 listenaddress=127.0.0.1 connectaddress=10.0.2.2 connectport=80
```

and now if you browse `http://localhost` it'll pass on the request to port 80 on the host.

---

If netsh doesn't work for you / your guest isn't Windows, but you've got **ssh** access between guest and host, you can run this from the guest: `ssh -L 80:localhost:80 10.0.2.2` and now from the guest if you browse `http://localhost` it'll pass on the request to port 80 on the host.